# Find data of those where referenced object id equals to user._id

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am getting all the order details

For example:(example of one order)

```
{
    "customer": {
        "id": "5db6ac89d85a2c1c709a42da",
        "name": "Testing"
    },
    "product": {
        "id": "5dba78427af9e73b18bdbb22",
        "name": "image",
        "seller": "Testing",
        "price": 100,
        "imgurl": "ok"
    },
    "_id": "5dba788fdeb78931f8a30105",
    "quantity": 3
}
```

When I use find() I get all the elements but I only want to show the data of the one who is logged in 
i.e where customer.id equals to req.user._id
I am using find() as shown in the code below:

```
router.get('/cart',verifyToken, async (req, res)=>{
const order = await Order.find({/* what should be the query here to get the desired result*/},'product , quantity , customer ');
try{
    res.send(order)
}catch(err){
    res.status(400).send(err);
}});
```

Any other methods to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `findOne()`.Like below

```
const order = await Order.findOne({'customer.id':req.user._id}) // probably req.body.user._id
```

or

```
await Order.findOne( { customer: { id:req.user._id } } )
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/)

Comment: I used const order = await Order.findOne({'customer.id':req.user._id}) and it worked I just wanted to ask why const order = await Order.findOne({customer.id:req.user._id}) was giving errors but in this format it worked? thanks a lot for solution